# Basic Square root program

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a program that calculates the square root of a number using the ancient Babylonian averaging method. The goal of the program is to display the number the user entered, the value of the averaging method, the value using the math package, and the difference between the averaging method and the math package. The only problem I am encountering is that the output of the difference comes out to 0.000. Could someone please help me get the actual difference between both methods. Here is my code for the program :

```
import java.util.*;
public class SquareRoot
{
    static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int k;  
        double number;
        double number2; 
        double generator ;
        double Difference; 

        generator = (int)(Math.random() * 20 + 1); // generates a random number between '1' and '20' 

////////////////////////Take input from the user/////////////////////////////////////////////////////        
        System.out.print("Please enter the number that you want to take the square root of: ");
        number = console.nextDouble();


 //////////////////////////generate the square root using the averaging method///////////////////////       
        for( k = 1; k <= 10; k++ )
        {
            generator = ( generator + (number/generator)) / 2;
        }    

////////////////////////Place the math package value in 'number2' and take the difference of the////// 
/////////////////////// averaged value and the true math package value//////////////////////////////// 
        number2 = Math.sqrt(number);

        Difference = (number2 - generator);

///////////////////////////////Display the results to the user////////////////////////////////////////       
        System.out.println("\nNumber    SquareRoot  MathPackage Difference");
        System.out.printf("%-6.3f    %-10.3f  ", number, generator);
        System.out.printf("%-11.3f %-10.3f%n" , number2 , Difference);




    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your random number generator is off a little bit. You want something like

```
double generator = 1 + (Math.random() * 20);
```

when I make that correction your existing code works fine. However, I would recommend you not declare your variables until you're ready to initialize them. Also, I suggest you follow the Java naming convention of lower case camelCase variable names (`difference`). Finally, placing a `Scanner` around `System.in` in a `static` field seems unnecessarily complex. Putting it all together, your code might look something like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter the number that you want to take "
            + "the square root of: ");
    double number = console.nextDouble();
    double generator = 1 + (Math.random() * 20);
    for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
        generator = (generator + (number / generator)) / 2;
    }
    double number2 = Math.sqrt(number);
    double difference = (number2 - generator);
    System.out.println("\nNumber    SquareRoot  MathPackage Difference");
    System.out.printf("%-6.3f    %-10.3f  ", number, generator);
    System.out.printf("%-11.3f %-10.3f%n", number2, difference);
}
```

#### Update

After 10 iterations, the babylonian method will have produced an answer that is very accurate (to the range of `double`). Try printing in the loop. Something like,

```
double number = console.nextDouble();
double number2 = Math.sqrt(number);
double generator = 1 + (Math.random() * 20);
System.out.println("Iteration    SquareRoot     Difference");
for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
    generator = (generator + (number / generator)) / 2;
    double difference = (number2 - generator);
    System.out.printf("%10d %-11.3f %-10.10f%n", k + 1, number2, difference);
}
```

Then you will see the approximated `difference` approach `0`.

Comment: Your code doesn't change the amount of decimals, which is what he is looking for. I ran your code and the difference is still 0.000

Comment: Try `109300`. The babylonian method is slow, not inaccurate.

Comment: You are right in terms of the babylonian accuracy; I just ran the program with 50 decimals and there was no difference. However, I still feel you kind of just fixed up his code and didn't really answer his question.

Comment: @BenjaminLowry Updated. On reflection, I believe OP is most interested in the `difference` as the approximation is calculated.

Comment: Yes that may be true, he should probably clarify at this point. I went ahead and changed my DV to an UV.

Answer (score 0):

In order to change the number of decimals displayed, you need to change your calls to `printf`.

In the below code, the number of after the decimal (in this case 3) specifies how many digits after the decimal are displayed.

```
System.out.printf("%-6.3f    %-10.3f  ", number, generator);
System.out.printf("%-11.3f %-10.3f%n", number2, difference);
```

In order to display more digits (for example 10) increase that number to a much higher one. Like this:

```
System.out.printf("%-6.10f    %-10.10f  ", number, generator);
System.out.printf("%-11.10f %-10.10f%n" , number2 , Difference);
```

If you run the same code with that simple change your output will change to:

```
Number    SquareRoot  MathPackage Difference
109300.0000000000    330.6055107088  330.6055050963 -0.0000056125
```

You might need to mess with formatting a little, but other than that it works.

For more information on this kind of string replacement works, see the documentation on the [Formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) class.

Comment: Wasn't entirely sure if this was what you were asking, but [Benjamin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35422852/basic-square-root-program/35423113#comment58546021_35422934) made it sound like that.